# Action-Reducer Mapping has type error with multiple action types

Tags: typescript, redux

[I asked a question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299124/using-typescript-types-to-ensure-that-all-action-types-are-handled-by-a-reducer/60299376#60299376), based on my attempts to create a mapping between redux-action-types and reducers to handle each of those types, with the requirement that each action type is handled explicitly.

I received a great answer on how to do that, and I can now create such a mapping, but I'm getting an error when I try and use it to create a reducer.

If I have the following code (sorry, it's rather long, but I believe it is a minimal example):

```js
export type IActionReducerMapping<S, A extends IReduxAction<string>> = {
    [K in A['type']]: IReducer<S, Extract<A, { type: K }>>
};

interface IUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface IUserState {
    [id: number]: IUser;
}

interface IAddUserAction {
    type: 'ADD_USER';
    payload: IUser;
}

interface ISetUserNameAction {
    type: 'SET_USER_NAME';
    payload: {
        id: IUser['id'];
        name: IUser['name'];
    }
}

type UserAction = IAddUserAction | ISetUserNameAction;

const mapping: IActionReducerMapping<IUserState, UserAction> = {
    'ADD_USER': (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        [action.payload.id]: action.payload,
    }),

    'SET_USER_NAME': (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        [action.payload.id]: {
            ...state[action.payload.id],
            name: action.payload.name,
        }
    }),
};

const userReducer = (state: IUserState, action: UserAction) => mapping[action.type](state, action);
```

I get the following error:

> Argument of type 'UserAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IAddUserAction & ISetUserNameAction'.
>     Type 'IAddUserAction' is not assignable to type 'IAddUserAction & ISetUserNameAction'.
>       Type 'IAddUserAction' is not assignable to type 'ISetUserNameAction'.
>         Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>           Type '"ADD_USER"' is not assignable to type '"SET_USER_NAME"'.ts(2345)

I can't see where I'm going wrong with the typing of these, could anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

[Here's the playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Qeyr+22jFInG2rWLuhLCcSZXKFSWW6hdCOkNWCrX60Ymw2Nxn22Vt2O+3TByRwQfNTwjyfO5WkJfVQOh5OH4a+aIL72H4Nua34PjIU4zjMsghkgYZkN88brEUpbpia3xppuFYBKIWZZLubARhE0QvgEDYYk0KGYduTjiEAA)

---

Edit:

The following works:

```js
const userReducer = (state: IUserState, action: ISetUserNameAction | IAddUserAction) =>  {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_USER':
            return mapping[action.type](state, action);
        case 'SET_USER_NAME':
            return mapping[action.type](state, action);
    }
}
```

Presumably because at this point the compiler is confident that it can know that the type of action and reducer will work nicely together. Still a mystery how I infer this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a separate function to transform a mapping to a reducer:

```js
export const reducerOf = <S, A extends IReduxAction<string>>(mapping: IActionReducerMapping<S, A>) =>
    (state: S, action: A): S =>
        mapping[action.type](state, action);
```

Now I can simply call it as:

```js
const userReducer = reducerOf(mapping);
```