# Correct TypeScript typing for a reducer, with merged action handler objects

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a reducer (state, action) -> state such that I can define various action handlers in separate objects, merge them together, and call them without a switch statement:

```
const allHanders = {
  ...aHandlers,
  ...bHandlers,
}

function reducer(state: State, action: AllActions): State {
  return allHandlers[action.type](state, action.payload)
}
```

but I just can't quite get it working. I feel like I'm close, but just missing a trick somewhere.

Here's a [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYGcZQLxQN4CwAUFKVKJAFxQBEMNxZUYAhiADbIsAm1hJTMi2rpgAJ0SoA5ozIBfYnKgAffLNIUI1OgCYGA0qw5deag4LgjxkmeYVF7xTbAQoMAIRxmmm7e5oANOrMbJw8fMFMAEZWEtLB9o5EzjDs7PBIaOheGW6YKi6ZHsRO4NAAysAswNC4-EwAZsjIsTaKJUQQAB5gyGLA5GVQABIsqNzsEGIA8lEAVhAIADwAKpXVEAGFeVDdNePZeINUUKJxUgDcIcY8APzUAK6oANaoyADuqFByAHw4svUyABtADSUEk2yyQJomhoAF04dQABSRU5VGrUNbozaooxhUwAUS64hYy1yWS2R18UDBv2heJM8OCAEocH8sRsLrI5FyiMQ4FkBixRuNJmJ0NQRRMprMFst1jUtuSMDA-nVgjBkaINqzsH9tYqNTotdjdfrsUEHB0BRgBlEpWKJSMxtKZvNFsAlgrNpCPGrvGR3FYNmy0RtLUkbaIoCw0g6pk74265Z7vUq0sr0P7AaQAHT54Uux2Wpj53P2osJiMdBpPVxoKBiCDcB5wKZIg1aKBpmP11DUVLpPvoZnUb0B0hRgYAC0rYi8sfYSfQQNJRVzmjhwSbwAeYi+s9F7c7WzXblzDJ4zMUQA)

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60303392/1630530) with a solution, which I have tried in their playground link but it also doesn't work.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: THis is because you have a union of functions, this is almost always that you don't want to end up. You need to use intersection of functions. See my [article](https://catchts.com/react-props)

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mAQJ8m) is a quick fix with type assertion